# Can I specify an upload-folder in the django models that's derived from a certain value?

Tags: django, django-models

I've got a model in Django which has a field specified as following:

```
file = models.FileField(upload_to='data')
```

I want to specify a folder based on a foreign key that another field that this instance has. Is this possible? Can I, for example, use something like

```
file = models.FileField(upload_to='{}/uploads/'.format(self.category.upper()))
```

I haven't tried anything yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of directly passing the name, you can define a function that generates the path name as:

```
def generate_filename(self, filename):
    name = "%s/uploads/%s" % (self.category.upper(), filename)
    return name
```

Then you can change the upload_to field as:

```
file = models.FileField(upload_to=generate_filename)
```

Comment: can you explain why there's a parameter called ```filename``` in this function? How is that one specified when calling this method?

Comment: As per the official documentation [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to], making the upload_to field callable requires the function being called to use 2 arguments:instance(self in our case) and filename. Instance is the instance of the Model where the FileField is defined and the filename is the name of file being uploaded.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I've slightly corrected your answer so that it worked for me.